# Replace number in var with another number

Tags: php

I'm trying to fetch a number from a string, divide it by 3, and then replace the original number with the output.

```
$original = "55 dogs";
preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$original);

$str = $original/ 3;
round($str);

str_replace(numbers, newNumbers, $str);
echo $str;
```

I found the `str_replace` via google, but I'm not sure that that's the right approach for what I'm trying to achieve. If anyone knows a method, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: What is numbers and newNumbers in your code??

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't make sense. It uses undefined variables all over the place.

Comment: http://php.net/str_replace

Comment: Check out documentation for functions you are using. They are returning results and you are ignoring them.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using preg_replace_callback():

```
$original = "55 dogs";
$result = preg_replace_callback(
            '/(\d+)/',
            function($match) {
                // You can do whatever you want to do with the match here
                return round($match[0]/3); 
            },
            $original
    );
var_dump($result); // string(7) "18 dogs"
```